# Why doesn't printStackTrace() print anything?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, exception, printstacktrace

I am trying to catch errors made by my Android Java project.  I am using the code `exceptionVar.printStackTrace()`, but this doesn't print anything.  I was *hoping* that `printStackTrace()` would print the error to the Android Studio console, but nothing appears.  In fact, nothing happens at all! There is no indication, on my Android device or in Android Studio, that any errors occurred or were printed using `printStackTrace()`.

How do I make this method print the error to the Android Studio console? Is there a setting I can change to make printed errors appear on the console?

Comment: Try `printStackTrace(System.out)`

Comment: Or write to a logger.

Comment: Did you look at console or Logcat?  Because it writes to logcat.

Comment: Check the log or category level in the Ide.  You have to select the right category.  It is  usually right above the terminal console area.

Comment: Thank you! I have used `printStackTrace(System.out);` and am using the Logcat, and now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking at the Android Studio Logcat and using `printStackTrace(System.out)`.